# Vb.net auto generate string proxy for the value of .bytes as variable to be inserted in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hi help me with this please? how can i change the value of .bytes as a auto generated string? and also to be inserted in my database

```
Dim myconn As MySqlConnection
                    myconn = New MySqlConnection
                    myconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; user id=root ; password=; database=auto"
                    myconn.Open()

                    Dim comm As New MySqlCommand
                    comm.Connection = myconn

                    comm.CommandText = "insert into sample(name,template) values (@name,@result)"
                    comm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@name", nametxt.txt))
                    'i need to change the value of sample from bytes to unique auto generated strings 

                    comm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@result", sample.bytes))
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    msgbox("success")
```

and through research i found this snippets

```
Functon RandomString()
Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
Dim r As New Random
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For i As Integer = 1 To 8
    Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, 35)
    sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
Next
return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

but im getting an error at StringBuilder and i dont know how to implement it to my codes. so please help me modify and implement it to my codes. any help is much appreciated

Comment: Would you consider a GUID for your random unique string?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i suppose. but can you guide me into implementing it above? just the output of GUID become the value of sample in db?

Comment: Read the documentation link. Try it yourself and come back if you're still having issues.